# Glusterfs: mixing brick sizes

Tags: glusterfs

What happens when you mix brick sizes in Glusterfs? I found this answer, but unfortunately I do not see any answer. http://lists.gluster.org/pipermail/gluster-users.old/2013-January/012354.html

In this case, I am talking about adding a replica with a different setup of RAID and different sized disks. Overall, this ends up being 0.4TB more of disk space.

I assume it will either not work at all or not use the extra disk space. If it doesn't work at all, would it work if the volume was exactly the same size?